# Implementing MVC design pattern with Repositories and Mapping, C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, crud

I have a problem with implementing the CRUD operations by using repositories, view models, and mapping in my ASP.Net MVC project. The "details"(read the information about one object) and "index"(read the whole list of objects), controllers are working.

I am mapping the `Model` to `ViewModel` and then display it in `View`. But for `Create`, `Update` and `Delete` operations, I should map the `ViewModel` to the `Model`. Could you tell me where am I wrong?

**Model**

```
 public class User
 {
     [Key]
     public int Id { get; set; }

     [Required]
     public string Name { get; set; }

     [Unique]
     [Required]
     [MaxLength(100)]
     public string Email { get; set; }

     [Required]
     public string Password { get; set; }

     public string Phone { get; set; }

     public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }
}
```

**Base repository**

```
public class BaseRepository<T> : IBaseRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private RushHourContext db = null;
    private DbSet<T> table = null;

    public BaseRepository()
    {
        this.db = new RushHourContext();
        table = db.Set<T>();
    }

    public BaseRepository(RushHourContext db)
    {
        this.db = db;
        table = db.Set<T>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> SelectAll()
    {
        return table.ToList();
    }

    public T SelectByID(object id)
    {
        return table.Find(id);
    }

    public void Insert(T obj)
    {
        table.Add(obj);
    }

    public void Update(T obj)
    {
        table.Attach(obj);
        db.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public void Delete(object id)
    {
        T existing = table.Find(id);
        table.Remove(existing);
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

**Interface for Repository**

```
public interface IBaseRepository<T> where T : class
{
    IEnumerable<T> SelectAll();
    T SelectByID(object id);
    void Insert(T obj);
    void Update(T obj);
    void Delete(object id);
    void Save();
}
```

**Controller**

```
   private RushHourContext _db = new RushHourContext();
   private IBaseRepository<User> _repository = null;

   public UsersController()
   {
       this._repository = new BaseRepository<User>();
   }

   public ActionResult Index()
   {
       if (!LoginUserSession.IsStateAdmin)
       {
           return RedirectToAction("Login");
       }
       var users = _repository.SelectAll().ToList();
       var userViewModel = Mapper.Map<List<UserViewModel>>(users);
       return View(userViewModel);
   }

   public ActionResult Details(int? id)
   {
       var users = _repository.SelectByID(id);

       var userViewModel = Mapper.Map<UserViewModel>(users);
       return View(userViewModel);
   }

   public ActionResult Create(User user)
   {
       var users = _repository.Insert(user); // THIS CODE HERE IS WRONG

       var userViewModel = Mapper.Map<User>(users);

       return View(userViewModel);
   }
```

**UserViewModel**

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter User Name.")]
    [Display(Name = "User Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)]
    [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
   @model RushHour.ViewModels.UserViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}
<h2>Create</h2>


<div>
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()


    @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Users", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

       <div>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Id)</div> 
       <div>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Id)</div> 
       <div>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Id)</div>

        <div>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)</div>
        <div>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)</div>
        <div>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)</div>

        <div>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)</div>
        <div>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Password)</div>
        <div>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)</div>

        <div>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email)</div>
        <div>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email)</div>
        <div>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)</div>

        <div>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Phone)</div>
        <div>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Phone)</div>
        <div>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phone)</div>


        <div>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsAdmin)</div>
        <div>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.IsAdmin)</div>
        <div>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsAdmin)</div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: "I should Map the ViewModel to the Model. " - exactly - do just that. What is the issue that you are experiencing? Usually, there is a DTO, say `UserDto` that comes in as form data. You then map it to your `User` and redirect to details page for that newly created index.

Comment: Could you give me some example or link. It's my first time doing it and I am lost. I comment where is my problem. In my Create Controller // var users = _repository.Insert(user);

Comment: For the create function use `UserViewModel` instead of  `User`, and then map to `User` for saving to the database.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your model in your `Create` view is your `UserViewModel` and that should be passed into the controller, not `User`.
2. The pattern you have set up suggests the user will first be on the `Create` view while entering new user information.  So, they will navigate to this view without passing any objects to it on their first trip.  If that's the case, you'll want a parameterless constructor for the first visit where you'll just create a new `UserViewModel` and pass it in.  You're then navigating back to this view after user creation which will present a form to them and be very confusing for user experience.  You'll probably want to redirect to a confirmation page or the login page with a message saying user created.
3. Whenever you make changes to the data, EntityFramework won't make those changes until you call SaveChanges on the repository.  It's odd that you aren't saving your new user immediately after it being created.

[DbSet.Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.add(v=vs.113).aspx)

[DbContext.SaveChanges](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.savechanges(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges)

Answer (score 0):

For the create function use `UserViewModel` instead of `User`.  Then map from `UserViewModel` to `User` to insert in database. After, if you want to display the saved data, then return `UserViewModel` object.

Try the following code.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(UserViewModel userViewModel)
{ 
   var user = new User();
   var newUser = Mapper.Map(userViewModel, user); 
  _repository.Insert(newUser);
  _repository.Save();
  return View(userViewModel);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! 
That's my solution now.

Comment: `[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(UserViewModel userViewModel)
        {
            var user = new User();

            var newUser = Mapper.Map(userViewModel, user);
            _repository.Insert(newUser);
            _repository.Save();

            return View(userViewModel);
        }`

Comment: @Geya If it worked successfully, choose this answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(UserViewModel userViewModel)
    {
        var user = Mapper.Map<User>(userViewModel);
        _reoisitory.Add(user);
    }
```